# executeScript not work

Tags: javascript, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have some JS-scripts in my tests. I don't understand why, but it stoped working now. 
Maybe it happened after protractor updating (to version 3.3.0).
Maybe somebody know what may happend?

My scripts:

```
    PsComponent.prototype.getHighlightedText = function () {
  return browser.executeScript_(function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
      text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
      text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
  });
};
```

Result:

```
nothing
```

And:

```
    PsComponent.prototype.getCaretPosition = function () {
  return browser.executeScript(function (input) {
    if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
      var range = document.selection.createRange();
      var bookmark = range.getBookmark();
      var caret_pos = bookmark.charCodeAt(2) - 2;
    } else {
      if (input.setSelectionRange){
        caret_pos = input.selectionStart;
      }
    }
    return caret_pos;
  });
};
```

Result:

```
- Failed: JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering the question, but here are the similar functions we are using (I guess things like that would naturally come up in any browser test automation project):

```
this.getCaretPosition = function (elm) {
    return browser.executeScript(function () {
        var webElement = arguments[0];

        return webElement.value.slice(0, webElement.selectionStart).length;
    }, elm.getWebElement())
};

this.getInputSelection = function (elm) {
    return browser.executeScript(function () {
        var webElement = arguments[0];

        return webElement.value.substring(webElement.selectionStart, webElement.selectionEnd);
    }, elm.getWebElement())
};
```

Usage samples:

```
expect(helpers.getCaretPosition(amountInput)).toEqual(1);
expect(helpers.getInputSelection(amountInput)).toEqual("-100.00");
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great alternative for my methods and it works.) But it is kind of magic for me why my methods ain't working now...

Comment: @ЛилияСапурина nice! I think you guys are overcomplicating these functions, we are basically just using the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` of an element, no `window` or `document` object involved. Thanks.